# Media query for Drawer in Material-ui component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to set Width of `<Drawer>` component `50%` of screen on web and `90%` on mobile, but media query doesn't seems to work for material-ui components.

can anybody please help me on this ?

PS: I have tried this so far but not working

```
const drawerWidth = {
  width: '50%',
  '@media(minWidth: 768px)' : {
    width: '90%'
  }
}

<Drawer
    ....
    width={drawerWidth.width}
    ....
  >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am suggesting is you to try something like this.

```
// drawer.css
@media(minWidth: 780px) {
    .drawer {
        width: '90%';
    }
}

//DrawerComponent.js

import '/path/to/your/drawer.css';

//...

render() {
    return (<Drawer className="drawer" />)
}
```

**PS:** `width` prop might be overriding `style` even though you are not setting it so you might need to use `!important` on your CSS.

**UPDATE 1**

using `containerClassName` rather than `className` combining it with `!important` works.
There were couple of mistake on my previous code.

1. Its not `minWidth` its `min-width`
2. not `width: '90%'` its `width: 90%`

---

```
 // drawer.css
    @media (min-width: 780px) {
        .drawer {
            width: 90% !important;
        }
    }



 //DrawerComponent.js

    import '/path/to/your/drawer.css';

    //...

    render() {
        return (<Drawer containerClassName="drawer" />)
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Previous version makes the drawer keep open all the time when its between the size of media queries. Problem caused by the `transform: translate` value being calculated wrong.
I fixed this with the code below. Hope it helps.

```
 // drawer.css
    @media (min-width: 780px) {
        .drawer {
            width: 90% !important; // material-ui uses vw so 90vw works too
            transform: translate(-100%, 0px) !important; // translate(-90vw, 0px)
        }
        .drawer.open {
            transform: translate(0, 0px) !important;
        }
    }



 //DrawerComponent.js

    import '/path/to/your/drawer.css';

    //...

    render() {
        return (
            <Drawer containerClassName={`drawer ${(this.state.open ? 'open' : '' )}`} />
        )
    }
```

Comment: ohh you are suggesting this way, sorry man but again i already this way too, and again not working, if you have any same workaround can you please share the code on plunker ?

Comment: no worries man, i used error free code, working but not giving desired output as needed, when you add width , drawer keep opned in case of web by default dont know why,

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a brace pair could fix your issue:

```
const drawerWidth = {
  width: '50%',
  ['@media(minWidth: 768px)']: {
    width: '90%',
  },
};
```